# What happens if a HttpClient.execute() is interrupted?

Tags: java

I am calling HttpClient.execute() in a background thread. Does it throw an IOException, when I interrupt the thread?

Comment: it will stop excuting i guess. every time. without exceptions of how many times you are calling. it will stop every time.

Comment: I will... when I have time ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, at least I haven't ever seen it do so. Note that you can interrupt a download by checking `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` as you copy from the `httpEntity.getContent()`.

There is more discussion on closing connections in other states here http://old.nabble.com/Close-interrupt-HTTP-connections-td30299655.html